# Different Division Combinations In NFL

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, permutations, combinations

I am running an optimization to try to determine the best division alignment in the NFL. There are 32 teams in a league, in which 8 divisions are made up of 4 teams each. There are 35,960 potential division alignments. I need help though, because that number only accounts for the scope of a single division. What I am after is the number of leagues I can create using those divisions, with each team in the league being unique, of course. In other words, how many different 8 division groups could I make that include every single team (no duplicates), where both the order of teams in a division and the order of the divisions in the league are unimportant. Thanks for your help!

P.S. Is there an online calculator that I could use to visualize this?

Comment: How are you measuring "best" here?  Also, there are ways to optimize other than brute force enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

$$\frac{32!}{(4!)^8} = 2.390462 \times 10^{24}$$

This is an example of a "multinomial coefficient". You can imagine that basically what you are doing is assigning 8x4 "division letters", AAAABBBBCCCC..., etc., to 32 teams. If all the teams are lined up in order, There are 32! ways to assign the letters if they would be distinct, but for each such arrangement, there are $(4!)^8$ arragnments that lead to the same division assignment (reording the actually indistringuisable A's, B's, etc). Hence the total number is    $\frac{32!}{(4!)^8}$.

Note his number is also the same as

$$
{32 \choose 4}{28 \choose 4} \cdots {8 \choose 4}{4 \choose 4}
$$
i.e. we can think of the process of successively choosing 4 teams to fill each division.

Comment: Since OP said "and the order of the divisions in the league are unimportant", I think you need to divide by $8!$.